# \footcite and \autocite handle comma differently

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

`biblatex`, with `verbose-trad2` style, has different behaviors when you use `\autocite` and `\footcite`. It is weird because, in this context, `\autocite` calls `\footcite`.

Here is the problem (look the place of the comma):

```
\noindent test\autocite{author00:_title},\\
test\footcite{author00:_title},
```

Result :

[image]

Is it a bug or a feature?

MWE :

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
     hyperref,
     backend=biber,
     isbn=false,
     doi=false,
     url=false,
     date=year]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{biblio}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\noindent test\autocite{author00:_title},\\
test\footcite{author00:_title},


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I've heard that US and UK standards on where the comma belongs are different.  It sounds like one of the packages is trying to be "smart".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Perhaps verbose-trad2 style tries to be smart and to choose were to put the comma. However, rules changed according to the language and to specify French does not change anything. (In French typography, comma is always after the footnote)

Comment: It is the case that not all packages are multilingual; that is, a developer's national bias can creep into a package.  I'm guilty of it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature. Quoting from section 3.7.4. of the `biblatex` manual:

> In contrast to other citation commands, the `\autocite` command does
>   not only scan ahead for punctuation marks following its last argument
>   to avoid double punctuation marks, it actually moves them around if
>   required. For example, with `autocite=footnote`, a trailing
>   punctuation mark will be moved such that the footnote mark is printed
>   after the punctuation.

In other words, if you're using `\footcite` instead of `\autocite`, you're responsible for the correct placement of punctuation marks. The two commands will feature the same behaviour in the following code snippet:

```
\noindent test,\autocite{author00:_title}\\
test,\footcite{author00:_title}
```

Comment: Thanks. In my opinion, it is a bad feature. `/autocite` should retrieve the information of the language from babel and place the comma before or after the footnote according to the regional typography rule.

Comment: @ppr You're missing the point of the feature. `\autocite` is style independent. So you can cite with this command and switch between, say, `verbose-trad2` and `authoryear` without worrying about the location of punctuation. Which punctuation should be moved is not entirely determined by the document language, although you can make this so with (for example) `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\DeclareAutoPunctuation{}}`.

Comment: @Audrey `\autocite` is really useful (because you can change the style afterwards) but it is a lot less useful when I notice it cannot handle different typography rules than english ones....

Comment: @ppr It can - I gave an example above. In English, punctuation typically comes before the footnote mark. However this is not always the case (see *Nature*'s style for example). You can specify which punctuation gets moved with `\DeclareAutoPunctuation`.